# Nasty character encoding issue

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, perl, encoding, charset

I have been using a FOSS software written in perl (sql-ledger) for many many years. Currently self hosted on CentOS 7. For some reasons, I need to update OS to a higher version (preferably Rocky/Alma 9).

Installed Apache and Postgresql 13, transferred all data and the software to a new Alma 9.

However, the non-english characters look garbled. No matter what I did, I couldn't fix it.

Here are what I did and findings:

- If the software is on CentOS 7, the database is on the new OS, all fine.
- Checked all the texts of the software. All are encoded as UTF-8.
- Encoding of the database is UTF-8. All data on the database look nice using Adminer.
- Installed Rocky/Alma 8 and Ubuntu 22.04, the problem persists.
- Tried many different versions of PostgreSQL, the problem persists.
- Source code of the served pages declare UTF-8 as character encoding.
- I normally use Firefox. Tried other browsers, the problem persists.
- All the new OS have the required UTF-8 locale.

The only solution for me is to have the software files on CentOS 7 irrespective of database location.

I'm at my wit's end with this problem. I am stumped and stuck with CentOS 7.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: The [FAQ of sql-ledger](https://sql-ledger.com/cgi-bin/nav.pl?page=misc/faq.html&title=FAQ) has multiple entries for encoding problems. Did you try them out?

Comment: I am one of the translators of this software. Checked the page you indicated. Nothing new. It has been working for almost 20 years without any problem until the new OSs. Thanks.